# How to change the position of divs in html based on window size

Tags: html, html-table

I have some divs that I'm using to encapsulate some graphs. Right now I'm using a table to align my divs like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div> My stuff </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div> My stuff </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, when my screen is smaller, I want this to become two rows where my divs are stacked. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Right now I also have a side menu on my page, so on a small screen the side menu appears first and then my table gets pushed below it. Instead, I want my side menu to be on the left and my divs on the right. Should I add my side menu to the table also?

Comment: Read about media queries and responsive webdesign

Comment: @Jost is right, what you're talking about will need responsive web design. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design. Basically you have different rules in your stylesheet for different screen sizes.

Comment: I did see where I could change my css using media types. However, this would allow me to apply styles based on the window size. How could I have css to rearrange a whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply style your divs to float left and relatively inherit first div's width as a margin by next div

```
<div class="firstdiv">My Stuff 1 </div>
<div class="seconddiv"> My Stuff 2</div>
```

And in your style do something like

```
.firstdiv{
float:left;
}
.secondiv{
float:left;
margin:auto
}
```

This will be responsive too. Hope this will help

2 About the Side Menu

Now enclose your divs in a container div and apply the same above descrbed method considering ur side menu as first div and stuf container as seconddiv